# Having trouble removing index.php from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

So far I have a fresh install of 2.1.3 and have placed an .htaccess file with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

in the root directory, same level as application, system, etc.

- Edited `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to
  `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application\config\config.php`.
- Turned on `rewrite_module`.
- Restarted Apache.

But I still end up with a 404 even after trying all the solution, even those in related posts.

Comment: RewriteCond $1, what is $1 here?

Comment: @Akam He is using the standard code provided in the docs with that

Comment: what is the structure of your site? public_html/site or just public_html

Comment: I haven't done a single thing yet, so far am trying to run localhost/welcome, instead of localhost/index.php/welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your httpd.conf to enable mod_rewrite and make sure that your webroot directory has AllowOverride set to 'ALL'

Comment: I already did. `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is un-commented.

Comment: do you have AllowOverride set to 'ALL' for your webroot?

Comment: Yes i do have it set to all.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this could help this is my htaccess and it works for me.

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /codeigniter/

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

use this it will work

Comment: pleasse put your htaccess file with index.php